# Font Face Browser Compatibility Issue

Tags: css, font-face

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'otto';
    src: url('font/otto.eot') format('embedded-opentype'), 
    url('font/otto.woff') format('woff'), 
    url('font/otto.ttf')  format('truetype'),
    url('font/otto.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
}
```

Seems to work perfectly in Chrome but in just about everything else it renders a totally different font which is much larger and looks awful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
@font-face{
    font-family:otto;
    src: url('../font/otto.eot');
    src: url('../font/otto.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../font/otto.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../font/otto.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('../font/otto.svg#Otto') format('svg');
}
```